# Carrierwave - Save nil if the image is not uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

i am trying to migrate images from local file system to dropbox, so i am using carrierwave dropbox gem to move all images to dropbox. i am able to store new images which is uploaded from my application. I am trying to move the existing images.

i am using Article.first.avatar? method to check whether the image exists or not, i have used this method in many places for different sizes of images in my application.

when i use the above method to find out whether the image exists or not, it says true always when the image is not present in dropbox. Look at my console output(2),

My uploader:

```
class Avatar < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
storage: file
def store_dir
    if model
      "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}/#{mounted_as}"
    else
      "uploads/#{mounted_as}/"
    end
 end 
end
```

console output (1)

```
>Article.first.avatar?
>false
#<AvatarUploader:0x007f9813f1fe70
 @file=
  #<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x007f9813f1e688
   @content_type=nil,
   @file="/Users/work/project/app1/public/uploads/370/avatar/avatar.png",
   @original_filename=nil>,
 @model=
  ##Article model
 @mounted_as=:avatar,
 @storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::File:0x007f9813f1fad8 @uploader=#<AvatarUploader:0x007f9813f1fe70 ...>>,
 @versions={}>
```

I changed uploader as follows:

```
class Avatar < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
    storage: dropbox
    def store_dir
        if model
          "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}/#{mounted_as}"
        else
          "uploads/#{mounted_as}/"
        end
     end 
    end
```

console output(2)

```
>Article.first.avatar?
>true
    #<AvatarUploader:0x007f8574143ee8
@file=
 #<CarrierWave::Storage::Dropbox::File:0x007f8574143308
  @client=
  #<DropboxClient:0x007f8574143420
   @root="dropbox",
   @session=
    #<DropboxSession:0x007f8574143498
    @access_token=#<OAuthToken:0x007f8574143470 @key="123453333",      @secret="22222222222">,
   @consumer_key="abcdeafs",
   @consumer_secret="asdfasfj",
   @locale=nil,
   @request_token=nil>>,
   @config=
{:app_key=>"asdfasfasf",
 :app_secret=>"asdfkasfksf",
 :access_token=>"adfkjasfkhs",
 :access_token_secret=>"aksdfkhsfksf",
 :access_type=>"dropbox",
 :user_id=>"292929292"},
 @path="uploads/images/370/avatar.png",
 @uploader=#<AvatarUploader:0x007f8574143ee8 ...>>,
 @model=
  #Artcle Model>,
  @mounted_as=:image,
  @storage=
  #<CarrierWave::Storage::Dropbox:0x007f8574143c90
   @config=
    {:app_key=>"asdfasfasf",
    :app_secret=>"asdfkasfksf",
    :access_token=>"adfkjasfkhs",
    :access_token_secret=>"aksdfkhsfksf",
    :access_type=>"dropbox",
    :user_id=>"292929292"},
   @dropbox_client=
  #<DropboxClient:0x007f8574143420
   @root="dropbox",
   @session=
```

1. why does it show "true" when the image is not present.
2. how can i get "false" when the image is not present in dropbox.

Comment: Can you describe question more specific? How image will not get uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

My stab in the dark is that inside Carrierwave, the normal file class it returns (sanitized file) responds to empty by checking if the file exists:

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/sanitized_file.rb#L144

Inside the carrierwave dropbox gem, the File class (https://github.com/robin850/carrierwave-dropbox/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/storage/dropbox.rb#L45) doesn't implement this. I'm guessing if you reopened the class and added

```
module CarrierWave
  module Storage
    class Dropbox < Abstract
      class File

        def empty?
          # use dropbox API to get the file and check the presence here
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It would probably work?

Comment: I added the above method in gem and tested by returning "false", But it always returns"true".                                                                                                           def empty?
  return false
end